# Throttling email frequency

Tags: email

I have a jobs board site running wp job manager which is generally fairly low on email sendouts but occasionally an action will trigger several hundred recipients to have an email update regarding a change in status of a listing or a status change by the employer on a list of applicants.

I currently use WP Mail SMTP sending via Dreamhost. Dreamhost have a limit on emails of 100 per hr. As these status updates and most emails from the site are not too time critical, I was looking for a solution to say queue the email instructions to send only 1 email per minute, and/or count the number sent in the past hr and when reached a certain cap number, delay the queue then start again.

Does this exist as a plugin (wp_mail integrated) anyone is aware of? Or is there another way to do this. I suppose I could send on something like Sendgrid, which I plan to do in future but as I already have a theoretical limit to send a max 2,400 emails a day I would rather better utilise that when starting out. Thanks.

Comment: I found this old free one https://wordpress.org/plugins/smtp-mailing-queue/ apparently someone is trying to take over its development to bring it up to date according to this discussion https://wordpress.org/support/topic/attachments-losts/

Comment: So my workaround was a free service called Mailgun, I set up a sub domain and sent the wordpress emails through that via WP Mail SMTP plugin settings, they have no hourly or daily limit on their free concept plan so long as under 10k emails per month total. Others I looked at all had like 200-300 hrly limit so if a job had more than 300 applicants it wouldn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check out this premium version one that integrates into `wp_mail`, but I suggest contacting or checking details on refund policy if it does not work for you:

https://shop.milandinic.com/downloads/simple-email-queue-plus/

The premium version is required for `wp_mail` integration.

Comment: Good find, certainly looks like it was designed to handle my exact issue. Will update if buy it but pressing on with the free mailgun route for now.